# How to fix missing dependency in React applications using useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, discord.js

Getting this error in my console. Not sure how to handle them

I am passing in guildId, so im not sure why its logging this error

> src/utils/hooks/useFetchGuildBans.tsx
>
> Line 22:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:
> 'guildId'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Here is my useFetchGuildBans.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getGuildBans } from '../api';
import { GuildBanType } from '../types';

export function useFetchGuildBans(guildId: string) {
  const [bans, setBans] = useState<GuildBanType[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [updating, setUpdating] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getGuildBans(guildId)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setBans(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [updating]);

  return { bans, loading, error, updating, setUpdating };
}
```

Comment: `}, [updating, guildId]);` ?

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how I missed that. Much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, any decent IDE would highlight this error for you so you don't have to look too much. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getGuildBans(guildId)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setBans(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [updating, guildId]);
```

The second parameter of `useEffect` is called the dependencies array. The error message is saying that `guildId` is missing from this array.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what it needed. I appreciate it! I was running into walls with it. I like my console to be free of warnings and especially errors.